# Java - Copy & Paste Unicode to a string

Tags: java, unicode, io

I've got a program that, when asked for a visual representation of a class, outputs a string that contains Unicode characters. 
Technically, the program is also capable of parsing the visual representation back into its class structure.

However, if I copy & paste the visual representation and paste it back as input, the string that's read is buggy. Example:
`(¬(a) ∨ ((¬(b) ∧ (c ∧ d)) ∨ e))` turns into `(Â¬(a) â¨ ((Â¬(b) â§ (c â§ d)) â¨ e))`

Question:
How do I process an input that contains Unicode to get a String that's a faithful representation of the input?

Comment: Are you sure your terminal isn't mishandling the encoding?  Prints fine in mine.

Comment: @Makoto How can you try that without the code Sudix uses for outputting and parsing?

Comment: Have you first created a string out of the input, and then printed the string?

Comment: @Lothar:  I took what Unicode they had pasted here, and pasted it into my machine.  My terminal handles Unicode correctly because I'm using the Hack font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corrupted data is the result of parsing binary data that represents `UTF-8` encoded text back into a `String` while using a different charset, e.g. `ISO-8859-1`. Your question doesn't contain any code that shows how you output and parse data so I can only give a general solution:

If you read in the data using `InputStreamReader`, use

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sourceInputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Don't use `FileReader` if data comes from a file because this is using the system's charset that might be different from `UTF-8`

If you read in the data already available as `byte`-array:

```
String text = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

If that doesn't help you need to provide more information, namely the code you have to parse the data and an explanation where the input comes from.

Comment: I basically copied "(¬(a) ∨ ((¬(b) ∧ (c ∧ d)) ∨ e))", and created a new String in the main method of the project out of it. However, when I looked at the String, it looked totally different. Since the encoding of IntelliJ is set to UTF-8, I thought it's something with Java, so I tried asking it as general as possible, but unkowningly altered the question this way. I'm sorry for missing the point of my own question. What I really wanted to ask is "Why looks the string different", and "What do I have to do so it doesn't"

Comment: @Sudix Post your code. The reason why this happens is explained in my answer. Why it's happening in your case can't be said without the code.